# How to set position of textLabel in a tableview cell iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

- In my table view i was using UITableviewCEllStyleValue1:

---

```
 if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

     cell.textLabel.text = @"Hai";
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hello";

        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        return cell;

        }
```

---

- Here two labels text labe, detailTextLabel are displayed.
- but not in the position what i want.
- I need to display Textlable from starting position of the cell (0,0) and immidiate right side position is detailTextlabel no gap between two labels.
- I need a solution with out using Allignment. what to do?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You have to create custom cell for this. like this,

> in CustomCellTableViewCell.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,strong)UILabel *lblUnit;
@end
```

> ```
> in CustomCellTableViewCell.m file
> ```

```
#import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomCellTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.lblUnit = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        [self.lblUnit setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [self.lblUnit setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:30.0f]];
       // [self.lblUnit setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
        self.lblUnit.textAlignment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
        self.lblUnit.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.lblUnit];
       }
    return self;
}

@end
```

> ```
> in your Tableview CellForRowAtIndexpath write below code
> ```

```
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[CustomCellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

     cell.lblUnit.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 150, 40);
     cell.lblUnit.text = @"Hai";
     return cell;
```

Comment: the default cell.textlabel is not movable

Comment: What's the hell of is this..!! I Was mentions that custom cell, then why down vote ?

Answer (score 8):

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and override the `layoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 0):

NSTextAlignmentCenter does work if you use initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault.